# Python, append within a loop

Tags: python, list, loops, append, product

So I need to save the results of a loop and I'm having some difficulty.  I want to record my results to a new list, but I get "string index out of range" and other errors.  The end goal is to record the products of digits 1-5, 2-6, 3-7 etc, eventually keeping the highest product.

```
def product_of_digits(number):
        d= str(number)
        for integer in d:
            s = 0
            k = []
            while s < (len(d)):
                j = (int(d[s])*int(d[s+1])*int(d[s+2])*int(d[s+3])*int(d[s+4]))
                s += 1
                k.append(j)
            print(k)

product_of_digits(n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question some time ago. Hi Chauxvive

This is because you are checking until the last index of `d` as `s` and then doing `d[s+4]` and so on... Instead, you should change your `while` loop to:

`while s < (len(d)-4):`

Comment: THAT was why you said to do that! Thanks!!

Comment: @chauxvive, Yep. There are no accidents. Everything happens for a reason. :) If my answer helped, could you accept it? Thanks

Comment: Yep!  Had to wait until the timer was up.  Thanks again.